# Can a security equity stock change its lising currency?

Tags: stock-market

I am looking at the financial data structure at some DB and see that the candle price of security equity shares is identified via the compound key of a financial instrument of 3 parts. A custom equivalent of share class FIGI, MIC (exchange that reported candle price), and a timestamp of the candle.

The currency of the candle is derived from the listing currency of such equity at some exchange.

The question: Is it possible that a ticker symbol may change listing currency and if yes how it is reflected on its ISIN/CUSIP do they change or stay the same?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not an economics question.

Comment: I’ve encountered some exchanges that allow listing in several currencies @H2ONaCl so I wanted to understand what are the implications for the trader. How does it work in the real world of trading that traded in one currency and a listing might change that?